# Postgresql - Creating new databsae using pgadmin3 version 1.16

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, postgresql-9.2, pgadmin

I have a basic question.  I don't know how to specify the version of the database I want to create using pgadmin3. 
I'm running pgadmin3 version 1.16.1 and i thought I could create databases that were version 9.2 pgsql.
But everytime I create a new database using the GUI and then I check the version, it's only at 9.1.
Sorry for the remedial question, but I'm just new at postgresql and pgadmin3. 
thanks.

**EDIT 1**

One problem was that I didn't have the 9.1 version of postgres installed.  so i just updated that package from 9.1 to 9.2... 
Then I used pgadmin3 to create a new database... and from the command-line, I connected to the new db to see what version it is and here's what I got:

```
me@mydevserver:~$ psql -U username testdb -h 127.0.0.1
Password for user openser: 
psql (9.2.4, server 9.1.9)
WARNING: psql version 9.2, server version 9.1.
         Some psql features might not work.
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

testdb=# select version();
                                               version                                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.1.9 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 32-bit
(1 row)

testdb=#
```

As you can see, the new testdb is still at 9.1.9. 
Can you tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create PostgreSQL database with version you want using SQL or any tool like PgAdmin.
Database version is a `PostgreSQL server software version` and can be changed only by upgrading or downgrading it. This task is sometimes tricky because of some incompatibilities between versions - especially when downgrading.

It's possible to have two or more PostgreSQL running servers (the same or different version) on the same machine - they must listen on different sockets/ports.

To summarize - when you make a connection to specific PostgreSQL server, all databases you create and access are in the same version as PostgreSQL server version.

Comment: infact, i did upgrade the server.. but what I just discovered is that I had two servers running - 9.1 and 9.2.  My mistake was that I assumed installing 9.2 would overwrite 9.1.  But it didn't. I've just uninstalled everything and am reinstalling 9.2.

Comment: I told you in this answer that it's possible to have two different version of server software.

Comment: I just uninstalled 9.1 and 9.2  Then reinstalled 9.2.  Now I can't remember the default postgres password!. ugh

Comment: I was referring to your last comment - "I can see - you have only upgraded psql client and not the server" which was incorrect.

Comment: If you don't remember password - find file `pg_hba.conf` probably in /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf - change authentication type for localhost and 127.0.0.1 to `trust` temporarily. Then restart postgresql, log in without password, set new password for user `postgres`, restore values in pg_hba.conf and restart postgresql.

Comment: strange... two things.  1) the folder structure I have is:/var/lib/postgresql/9.2/main# .  I can't get to main unless I'm root.  and 2) once i su to root, in main, I don't have a data folder or the file pg_hba.conf.  maybe something with uninstall / install messed up

Comment: ElmoVanKielmo, here's what I've found.  had to edit /etc/postgresql/9.2/main.  changed everything there to trust.  then via command line, tried to log in to postgres database using user postgres.  it worked.  no prompt for password.  then I reran the "passwd" commnd to reset password for the user "postgres".  changed the pg_hba.conf file back to peer and md5 which is what it had before.  retried the command line connection and it prompts again for password.  I type in new password... and it fails. FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres" is the message I get

Comment: I got it to work.  followed your steps.. but also had to remove the server reference in pgadmin and then repeat all steps before it worked.

Comment: Nothing strange: exact path of postgres data files varies in different linux distributions, indeed ordinary user has no access to these folders and files so you had to sudo first (sorry, I thought you knew about it). I haven't used md5 authentication here - always used passwd - maybe this caused trouble after password reset. And finally yes, sometimes it is needed to adjust pgadmin config .I'm glad you managed to make it work.